# Policy based authorization on razor pages

Tags: .net-core

I trying to set up policy-based authorization on razor pages on Core2.1.

I have set up the policy and decorated the razor page with the authorize attribute. I cannot figure what am I doing wrong or if something else needs to be done, but I cannot get the page to authorize. It always gives me

> No web page was found for the web address:
>
> localhost/ADENETCore/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FADENETCore%2FContact

Can you please point me in the right direction?

**ConfigureServices:**

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("AtLeast21", policy =>
                        policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
                });
            services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                    {
                        options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Contact", "AtLeast21"); // with policy
                    })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
```

**Configure:**

```
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
```

**Policy Requirement:**

```
    public class MinimumAgeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
     public int MinimumAge { get; private set; }

     public MinimumAgeRequirement(int minimumAge)
     {
      MinimumAge = minimumAge;
     }
    }
```

**Policy Handler:**

```
public class MinimumAgeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MinimumAgeRequirement>
        {
            protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                           MinimumAgeRequirement requirement)
            {
    context.Succeed(requirement);
     return Task.CompletedTask;

    }
}
```

**Razor Page:**

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AtLeast21")]
public class ContactModel : PageModel
```

It is redirecting to the `Account/AccessDenied` page

Comment: what is your expected behavior? it is supposed to redirect to this location of the authorization fails.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane May be I am missing something but i am expecting it to Authorize the contact page since I have passed the requirement in the Handler Class (context.Succeed(requirement);return Task.CompletedTask;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your authorization handlers as singletons.

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MinimumAgeHandler>();
```

For more info check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I remember exploring this documentation a while back. Adding this singleton is key. Most of the rest is not mandatory.